# ¿como puedo regresar a un commit en especifico y despues descargar el proyecto entero apartir de ahi?

Tags: git, github

alguien me pudiera ayudar y hacerme saber si es posible y como, poder regresarme a un commmit en especifico para poder ya sea clonar o descargar el proyecto desde dicho commit hacia atras, es decir el proyecto completo hasta el commit Deseado.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar SourceTree es un gestor de repositorios, tiene una interface gráfica bastante sencilla, una vez que agregues el repositorio, con el puedes ver todos los commits que tiene tu repositorio y con solo hacer doble clic en dicho commit podrás regresar al commit que tu desees

Comment: No veo claro si quieres hacer pull de tal forma que te baje sólo hasta un cierto commit (lo cual no sé si es posible), o si te vale con bajarte el repositorio completo pero después "retroceder" al estado en que estaba en un commit concreto, en cuyo caso es bien fácil: `git clone` del proyecto seguido de `git checkout` del commit concreto.

Comment: Hola, si la respuesta fue en parte la segunda que me diste, clone & checkout ademas de complementarla con ayuda de las respuestas de abajo. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555202/9015852) está la solución:

```
git clone https://github.com/usuario/my-repo-name.git my_repo
cd my_repo
git reset --hard [Hash del commit que quieres]
```

Comment: fue de gran ayuda, Gracias

Comment: una duda
¿El repositorio que clono se hara en un nuevo repositorio o nueva branch?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias bajarte el repositorio y devolverse entre heard utilizando el comando:

```
$ git checkout <hash> --hash es el numero del commit
$ git checkout HEAD~2
$ git reset --HEAD.
```